# Compare Harvest to other source control systems?

Tags: version-control, harvest-scm

From the top, "source control" seems like a bad way to describe CA Harvest; it's a deployment control system, and it's actually pretty good at just deploying code.  I've found it to be lacking when doing source control tasks, though.

If you've used Harvest;

1. what did it do right?
2. what couldn't it do?
3. what did it do with a workaround so hackish it took 3x longer than you'd expect?

Answer (score 4):

(Someone correct me if I'm wrong.)  Harvest seems awesome for deployment control, enforcing steps along a deployment lifecycle, and getting a chain of approval for deployments to production.  That said, it's missing on the developer-friendly side.

It seems like I need to use the Workareas; they let me put all the code on my local machine, so I can do development.

With Workareas, I can only synchronize from the repository, but not get a report of what just sync'ed in; I don't know what changed, or who changed it, or why.

To add comments to checkins using Workareas, you have to manually enable the functionality in the preferences, which is a huge red flag to me.

I can't seem to figure out how to find out what changed since a specific time; what changed since Friday at 5 PM, for example?

There aren't any atomic commits; I can't commit files as a group, then roll the group back later if something goes wrong.  I can do it as a package, but that's heavyweight; a package should be able to contain hundreds of atomic commits/groups.

And worst of all, it's entirely unsupported by Stack Overflow and/or any other question-and-answer site I can find.  If I can't figure it out... I'm shooting blind.

Answer (score 1):

We're currently migrating away from Harvest.

1. Configuration management and code deployment. We have a pretty good process flow going.
2. Branching and merging. Horrible SCM tool really.
3. ?